# Data does not retrive from back end to frond end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')
[Error Display only console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3ywO.png)

run the code clearly

Comment: ```error?.response?.status``` or define the type of error.

Comment: Hi, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)